# Filter attribute from a list of object nested in another list of object using stream

Tags: java, java-stream

For the following class structure, from a `List<SomeClass>`, for a given `name` and `fieldName`, I want to get a list of `fieldValue`s. There can be multiple occurrences of `name`

```
class SomeClass {
    String name;
    List<SomeField> fields;
}

class SomeField {
    String fieldName;
    String fieldValue;
}
```

This is what I have done so far without stream -

```
                for (SomeClass aClass : classes) {

                    if (aClass.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(givenName)) {

                        for (SomeField aField : aClass.getSomeField()) {

                            if (aField.getFieldName().equalsIgnoreCase(givenFieldName)) {

                                outputList.add(aField.getFieldValue());

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I have tried to convert this to stream, but I only reached till here. I could not figure out how to proceed to the next step (getting list of `SomeField` from this point and filtering based on `fieldName`) -

```
classes.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(givenName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Sample input:

```
  [
   {
      "name":"a",
      "fields":[
         {
            "fieldName":"n1",
            "fieldValue":"v1"
         },
         {
            "fieldName":"n2",
            "fieldValue":"v2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"a",
      "fields":[
         {
            "fieldName":"n1",
            "fieldValue":"v3"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"b",
      "fields":[
         {
            "fieldName":"n1",
            "fieldValue":"v4"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

for `givenName = "a"` and `givenFieldName = "n1"` :

expected output : `["v1","v3"]`

Comment: Can you add a simple List declaration for the loops you've provided? Is `getSomeField()` a getter for `List<SomeField> fields`?

Comment: yes. getSomeField() is a getter. did not include getters here. classes is a List<SomeClass>. classes.getSomeField() will return a List<SomeField>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flatMap` to flat the `List<SomeField>` then filter by condition then map only `fieldValue` and get the list of `fieldValue`.

```
List<String> res = classes.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(givenName))
            .flatMap(m  -> m.getSomeField().stream())
            .filter(f -> f.getFieldName().equalsIgnoreCase(givenFieldName))
            .map(e -> e.getFieldValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map()` and `flatMap()`.

```java
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String givenName = "a";
        String givenFieldName = "n1";
        
        List<SomeClass> classes = new ArrayList<>();
        classes.add(new SomeClass("a", List.of(new SomeField("n1", "v1"), new SomeField("n2", "v2"))));
        classes.add(new SomeClass("a", List.of(new SomeField("n1", "v3"))));
        classes.add(new SomeClass("b", List.of(new SomeField("n1", "v4"))));
        
        
        List<String> result = classes
                .stream()
                .filter(c -> c.name.equalsIgnoreCase(givenName))
                .flatMap(c -> c.fields.stream())
                .filter(f -> f.fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase(givenFieldName))
                .map(f -> f.fieldValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        System.out.println(result);
        
    }
    
}

class SomeClass {
    
    String name;
    List<SomeField> fields;
    
    public SomeClass(String name, List<SomeField> fields) {
        this.name = name;
        this.fields = fields;
    }
    
}

class SomeField {
    
    String fieldName;
    String fieldValue;
    
    public SomeField(String fieldName, String fieldValue) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.fieldValue = fieldValue;
    }
    
}
```